# Absence of anti-csrf tokens in authenticationendpoint cookies/headers of wso2 IS 5.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have tried all WSO2 guidelines for enabling the CSRF properties on network cookies and submit forms of GET methods of authenticationendpoint webapp but still not able to achieve the result.

I was getting "Absence of Anti-CSRF tokens" ZAP vulnerability for the authenticationendpoint in the response of the GET methods because it doesnt contain the hidden parameter - csrf token in form submit tag of the response body.

WSO2 Links referred:

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/administer/mitigating-cross-site-request-forgery-attacks/#securing-web-applications

https://wso2.com/technical-reports/wso2-secure-engineering-guidelines#C03

https://medium.com/@PrakhashS/overview-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-recommended-approach-for-wso2-products-bb0e2437307

Information provided in ZAP vulnerability:

```
No known Anti-CSRF token [anticsrf, CSRFToken, __RequestVerificationToken, csrfmiddlewaretoken, authenticity_token, OWASP_CSRFTOKEN, anoncsrf, csrf_token, _csrf, _csrfSecret] was found in the following HTML form: [Form 1: "tocommonauth" "username" "password" "chkRemember" "sessionDataKey" ].
```

web.xml of authenticationendpoint webapp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2014, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
  ~ Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
  ~ in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  ~ software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  ~ "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  ~ KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  ~ specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~ under the License.
  -->

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    <absolute-ordering />


    <!-- OWASP CSRFGuard context listener used to read CSRF configuration -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- OWASP CSRFGuard session listener used to generate per-session CSRF 
        token -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- OWASP CSRFGuard per-application configuration property file location -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
        <param-value>/repository/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- OWASP CSRFGuard filter used to validate CSRF token -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!-- OWASP CSRFGuard filter mapping used to validate CSRF token -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- OWASP CSRFGuard servlet that serves dynamic token injection JavaScript 
        (application can customize the URL pattern as required) -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/csrfguard.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>






    <!-- *************** Account Recovery Endpoint Context URL Configuration 
        ********************** -->
    <!--context-param> <param-name>IdentityManagementEndpointContextURL</param-name> 
        <param-value>https://localhost:9443/accountrecoveryendpoint</param-value> 
        </context-param -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>AccountRecoveryRESTEndpointURL</param-name>
        <param-value>/t/tenant-domain/api/identity/user/v1.0/</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- *************** End of Authentication REST API URL Configuration ********************** -->

    <!--Display scopes in the consent page. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>displayScopes</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationEndpointFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.filter.AuthenticationEndpointFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationEndpointFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>URLBasedCachePreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>URLBasedCachePreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>patterns</param-name>
            <param-value>"text/html" ,"application/json" ,"plain/text"</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filterAction</param-name>
            <param-value>enforce</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>httpHeaders</param-name>
            <param-value>
                Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.util.listener.AuthenticationEndpointContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>retry.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/retry.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>wait.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/long-wait.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>idf-confirm.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/identifier-logout-confirm.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dynamic_prompt.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/dynamic_prompt.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>handle-multiple-sessions.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/handle-multiple-sessions.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>claims.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/requested-claims.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_login.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_authz.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/oauth2_authz.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_consent.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/oauth2_consent.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_logout_consent.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/oauth2_logout_consent.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_logout.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/logout.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_error.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/oauth2_error.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_login.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_logout.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/logout.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_redirect.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_notification.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/samlsso_notification.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>openid_login.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>openid_profile.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/openid_profile.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>passivests_login.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/login.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>tenantlistrefresher.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/tenant_refresh_endpoint.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>registration.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/registration.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>consent.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/consent.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cookie_policy.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/cookie_policy.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>privacy_policy.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/privacy_policy.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>authenticate.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/authenticate.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>error.do</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/generic-exception-response.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>retry.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/retry.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>wait.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/wait.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>idf-confirm.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/idf-confirm.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dynamic_prompt.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dynamic_prompt.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>handle-multiple-sessions.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/handle-multiple-sessions.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_login.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth2_login.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_authz.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth2_authz.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_consent.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth2_consent.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_logout_consent.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth2_logout_consent.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_logout.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth2_logout.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>oauth2_error.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/oauth2_error.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_login.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/samlsso_login.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_logout.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/samlsso_logout.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_redirect.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/samlsso_redirect.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>samlsso_notification.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/samlsso_notification.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>openid_login.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/openid_login.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>openid_profile.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/openid_profile.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>passivests_login.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/passivests_login.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>tenantlistrefresher.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/tenantlistrefresher.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>registration.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registration.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>claims.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/claims.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>consent.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/consent.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cookie_policy.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cookie_policy.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>privacy_policy.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/privacy_policy.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>authenticate.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/authenticate.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>error.do</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/error.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/generic-exception-response.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <!-- custom error pages -->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_400.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_401.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_403.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>405</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_405.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>408</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_408.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>410</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_410.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_500.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>502</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_502.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>503</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_503.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>504</error-code>
        <location>/errors/error_504.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <location>/errors/error.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you upload the web.xml, so that we can reproduce

Comment: i have uploaded authenticationendpoint web.xml file, let me know if you need tomcat/carbon web.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

By default all the web applications shipped with the product are protected from the CSRF attacks[1]

> For WSO2 Identity Server, the configurations for mitigating CSRF
>   attacks are enabled by default for all the applications that are built
>   into the product. Therefore, you need to apply these configurations
>   manually, only if you have any custom applications deployed in your
>   product.

So you don't any extra configuration.

---

According to the information provided in ZAP vulnerability scan, it detects the commonauth request inside the authenticationendpoint web app as vulnerability. That is wrong let me explain why.

**What is authenticationendpoint webapp and commonauth request?**

In the WSO2 Identity server, authenticationendpoint serves the login, consents pages during the authentication. And the user actions (like credential, OTP code, federated login flows, consent approval) are submitted to the server using the commonauth request.
So these interactions happen from the browser before the user is not authenticated.

**What is CSRF?**[2]

> Cross-site request forgery (also known as CSRF) is a web security
>   vulnerability that allows an attacker to induce users to perform
>   actions that they do not intend to perform.

So as the user is not authenticated yet, there is no additional advantage the attacker can get by submitting those authentication pages.

So these are configured to be skipped from the CSRF protection. You can check those endpoints in IS_HOME/repository/conf/security/Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties file

```
# please remove the below entry to enable protection for services.
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.Services=%servletContext%/services/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.commonauth=%servletContext%/commonauth/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.samlsso=%servletContext%/samlsso/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.authenticationendpoint=%servletContext%/authenticationendpoint/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.wso2=%servletContext%/wso2/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.oauth2=%servletContext%/oauth2/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.oidc=%servletContext%/oidc/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.openid=%servletContext%/openid/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.openidserver=%servletContext%/openidserver/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.passivests=%servletContext%/passivests/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.acs=%servletContext%/acs/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.iwa=%servletContext%/iwa/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.oauthiwa=%servletContext%/commonauth/iwa/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.thrift=%servletContext%/thriftAuthenticator/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.mex=%servletContext%/mexut/*
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.identity=%servletContext%/identity/*
```

As you can see these are the endpoints used in the authentication flows.

[1] - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/administer/mitigating-cross-site-request-forgery-attacks/#configuring-applications-in-wso2-product-to-mitigate-csrf-attacks

[2] - https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @senthalan !! but after removing these entris from CSRF guard properties, I'm still getting the Anti-CSRF token vulnerability for POST methods also. It requires csrf token in saml sso response body and sso request for logout in the form submit.


org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.commonauth
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.samlsso
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.authenticationendpoint
org.owasp.csrfguard.unprotected.oauth2